# Запуск проекта на Node.js и настройка nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

Думаю, кому-нибудь будет полезно знать, как запустить проект на Node.js.

Первым делом необходимо установить саму ноду, но об этом я писать не буду, это размусоленно на триллионах сайтов. А вот как поднять проект на русскоязычных сайтах, инфы маловато. Сам я искал инфу на ру сайтах, но в итоге все равно пришлось питаться инфой из-за бугра.

Задача состоит в следующем:

1. Запустить ноду.
2. Писать лог по ошибкам.
3. Если сайт падает, надо его поднять.

Ставим upstart

```
sudo apt-get install upstart
```

Предположим, у вас есть проект site.ru, и расположен он в каталоге

```
/var/www/nodejs/site/
```

Создаем файл /etc/init/site.conf

```
#site.conf
description "node.js bin/www"
author      "username"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/root"

    echo $$ > /var/run/site.pid
    exec sudo -u username /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/nodejs/site/bin/www >> /var/log/site.sys.log 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/site.sys.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/site.pid
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/site.sys.log
end script
```

Далее открываем /ect/monit/monitrc

```
check process site with pidfile "/var/run/site.pid"
        start program = "/sbin/start site"
        stop program = "/sbin/stop site"
        if failed port 3000 protocol HTTP
            request /
            with timeout 10 seconds
            then restart
```

Где порт 3000, впишите свой, по умолчанию нода запускается с портом 3000.

Чтобы избавиться от порта в site.ru:3000,
правим конфиг nginx
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
        server_name site.ru www.site.ru;
        listen 37.143.15.183;
        charset UTF-8;
        set $root_path /var/www/nodejs/site;
        location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 120s;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
            proxy_pass http://37.143.15.183:81;
            proxy_redirect http://37.143.15.183:81/ /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://37.143.15.183:81;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.inc;
    }
```

Перезапускаем nginx

```
service nginx restart
```

Запускаем проект

```
start site
monit -d 60 -c /etc/monit/monitrc
```

Открываем site.ru, и если все в порядке, увидите приветствие от Express.

ПС. более подробно можно почитать на забугорном сайте

http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit

Comment: @webphp, это скорее исследование, а не вопрос. Перенесите в исследования.

Answer (score 1):

**я так понимаю эти строчки особо не нужны....это из личного конфига....верно?**

```
location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
    proxy_pass http://37.143.15.183:81;
    proxy_redirect http://37.143.15.183:81/ /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://37.143.15.183:81;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.inc;
```

Comment: да, из личного конфига

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо бы, как-то, с простого и понятного начинать. Чтобы "избавться" в адресной строке от порта :3000, нужно в `nginx.conf` напейсать:

```
http {
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

И фсё. Дальше уж можно углУбиться в настройки, но это - уже будет работать.